# Why perl omitting the @ strings

Tags: arrays, string, perl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$test ="@test=hello"; #(Actually am reading this text from File and assigning to a variable)

print "$test";
```

**After executing the above code perl outputs the below**

**Output**:

```
=hello instead of @test=hello.
```

Can anyone please explain the above. I believe that it is considering as empty array, but how can i avoid this when and reading a file, please clear my misconception.

Thanks,

Comment: You can put a backslash in front of the @ or use single quotes instead of double quotes

Answer (score 3):

Perl interpolates variables in strings delimited by double quotes.

`@test` is treated as an array.

Unless you have created this explicitly, you *should* get an error when you try to do that. If you don't then you must have forgotten to `use strict;` and `use warnings;`!

Use single quoted strings if you don't want to interpolate variables.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;

my $test = '@test=hello'; 
say $test;
```